# Snapping Tag and general tag organization

Tags: discussion, tags

There was a [tag discussion held in chat a while back](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/conversation/tags-discussion) to discuss which tags were too specific or too general and should be removed.

The decision was to remove the following tags:

[clipping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clipping)

[snapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snapping)

[charset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charset)

[parametric-modeling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parametric-modeling)

[projection](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projection)

[modules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modules)

[deformation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deformation)

[license](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license)

[data-vis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-vis)

[cell-fracture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-fracture)

[.stl](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.stl)

[dimensioning](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dimensioning)

And synonimize the following tags:

[coordinate-system](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinate-system) → [coordinates](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coordinates) (still not synonimized)

[library](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library) → [blendfile](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blendfile)

[unwrapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unwrapping) → [uv](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uv)

[manual](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manual) → [wiki](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiki)

[bsurfaces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bsurfaces) → [addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/addon) (removed)

---

Since then there has been [some discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/conversation/informal-tag-discussion-2) on whether or not [snapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snapping) should recreated as there are now roughly 24 [questions which could use this tag](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=snapping%20is:question).

The original reason for dropping the [snapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snapping) tag was because it fit inside the scope of [modeling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling), however since the site has since grown and there are more questions specifically about snapping it has been argued that perhaps a [snapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snapping) tag would be in order.

So now the questions about [snapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snapping) are

- Should it be revived
- If the answer to the above question is "yes", then the next question is whether or not old questions should be (re)tagged with [snapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snapping).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think tags should be created based on the popularity. Although some tags fall in the category of other tags, e.g. snapping → modeling, array → modifiers, there should still be a separate tag for them if these tags are popular. These kind of tags are likely to have a lot of associated questions. Having a specific separate tag would be good practice because if there are too few tags and too many questions which fall into the same general tag it would be harder for people to find the questions in the future.

---

I think snapping should be revived. Although it is part of modeling is has a lot of questions that could be associated with it.
And if we revive [snapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snapping) we should also add the tag to the questions that fall into that category.

Comment: What about the second question?

Comment: @gandalf3 added