# Tag Synonyms with no users

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, moderation

What are the reasons for making some of the tag [synonyms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)?

These tags have no users and are not needed but are still in the tag list because they are synonyms.
[glossy](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glossy)
[material-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material-nodes)
[bezier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bezier)

As any mod on blender exchange knows, I do I lot of re-tagging and clean up.  Is it not better to (when a tag is still small) re-tag the question or questions in stead of making a tag synonym?
A example is [collision](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collision) is a pending synonym for [rigid-body-simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rigid-body-simulation) why make it a synonym?

I ask for the synonyms [glossy](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glossy)[material-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material-nodes)[bezier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bezier) to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synonyms exist so that commonly used words which are incorrect can be remapped to the correct tag that should be used. Generally, our agreed upon policy is if the tag falls [under a broader one](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/349/12), merge/synonimize it.

The tags you mentioned have been been in the waiting list for sometime now. They have been removed.

Comment: when you say removed, you mean added to the list of synonyms. Why do you not just delete the synonym and then have SE cull the tag, because it is empty?

Comment: @David Gone now, apparently, the merge/delete didn't complete for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, those unused and unnecessary tags were bothering me. I like to keep the tags clean.